# Updating non PK fields in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

[image]

My `mainTable` has column primaryCode.  These codes are incorrect and need to be updated based on the `updateCodes` table.  The incorrect codes are in the column `primaryCode` on `mainTable` and `primaryCode` on the updateCodes table.  The descrip column is the correct version.  Since I'm not sure how `rollback` works, below is my query for fixing the problem; I think it's right, but not sure.

edit: There are many more codes in my mainTable than these.  These are just the ones that need to be updated.  I don't know if that will affect the query or not.

```
update mainTable
set mainTable.primaryCode=update.descrip
from mainTable
inner join updateCodes on mainTable.primaryCode=updateCodes.descrip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
UPDATE MainTable SET MainTable.primaryCode = UpdateCodes.descrip
FROM MainTable
INNER JOIN UpdateCodes 
ON MainTable.primaryCode = UpdateCodes.primaryCode
```

Joining on the values that are "wrong" to get the correct ones for the update...